# How can I edit `www.conf` for php-fpm in chef recipe?

Tags: chef-infra, php, berkshelf

By using `Berkshelf` I'm installing `php-fpm`.

And I want to comment out following lines in `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`:

```
;listen.owner = www-data
;listen.group = www-data
```

But I couldn't find where should I edit in `cookbooks/php-fpm` directory.
And I don't know if it is ok to edit files directly that is created by `Berkshelf` automatically.

Where and how can I reflect that change?

*Edit*

The problem is there is no `www.conf` in `php-fpm` template.
I think this file is somehow generated dynamically.
Does anyone know how the file `www.conf` generated?

This is the result of `find`.

```
find . -name '*.conf.*'
./templates/default/pool.conf.erb
./templates/default/php-fpm.conf.erb
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this line to `*.json` node config file, then the values are override.

```
php-fpm": { "listen_owner": "nginx", "listen_group": "nginx" },
```

Answer (score 1):

Hum, seems what you're looking for is overiding the template in php-fpm cookbook.

The best method would be to create a wrapper cookbook which will do that.

you can have a look here for that:
[Replacing a template in a wrapper cookbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933157/replacing-a-template-in-a-wrapper-cookbook/18472214#18472214)

for the php-fpm the configuration is done inside a definition (HWRP), have a look inside it to find the template call and see how to ovewrite it.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I'll use `rewind` resource. But I could't find the template file that should be overridden. Could you tell me where is it?

Comment: You can see the provider [here](https://github.com/yevgenko/cookbook-php-fpm/blob/master/definitions/php_fpm_pool.rb) Per default the template name would be "/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf" unless you're on rhel and it will be "/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf"